# Is there a sqlfluff function to return the query as a string given a parsed query?

Tags: python, sql, compilation, sqlfluff

sqlfluff can generate a parsed query as a dict using the function `.parse`, like in the example:

```py
import json
import sqlfluff


print(json.dumps(sqlfluff.parse(
    """with cte1 as (select colA from table1), cte2 as (select colB from table2 inner join table1 on table2.colB = table1.colA) select * from cte2""",
    "postgres"
), indent=4))
```

This results in the following

```json
{
    "file": {
        "statement": {
            "with_compound_statement": [
                {
                    "keyword": "with"
                },
                {
                    "whitespace": " "
                },
                {
                    "common_table_expression": [
                        {
                            "naked_identifier": "cte1"
                        },
                        {
                            "whitespace": " "
                        },
                        {
                            "keyword": "as"
                        },
                        {
                            "whitespace": " "
                        },
                        {
                            "bracketed": {
                                "start_bracket": "(",
                                "select_statement": {
                                    "select_clause": {
                                        "keyword": "select",
                                        "whitespace": " ",
                                        "select_clause_element": {
                                            "column_reference": {
                                                "naked_identifier": "colA"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "whitespace": " ",
                                    "from_clause": {
                                        "keyword": "from",
                                        "whitespace": " ",
                                        "from_expression": {
                                            "from_expression_element": {
                                                "table_expression": {
                                                    "table_reference": {
                                                        "naked_identifier": "table1"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "end_bracket": ")"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "comma": ","
                },
                {
                    "whitespace": " "
                },
                {
                    "common_table_expression": [
                        {
                            "naked_identifier": "cte2"
                        },
                        {
                            "whitespace": " "
                        },
                        {
                            "keyword": "as"
                        },
                        {
                            "whitespace": " "
                        },
                        {
                            "bracketed": {
                                "start_bracket": "(",
                                "select_statement": {
                                    "select_clause": {
                                        "keyword": "select",
                                        "whitespace": " ",
                                        "select_clause_element": {
                                            "column_reference": {
                                                "naked_identifier": "colB"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "whitespace": " ",
                                    "from_clause": {
                                        "keyword": "from",
                                        "whitespace": " ",
                                        "from_expression": {
                                            "from_expression_element": {
                                                "table_expression": {
                                                    "table_reference": {
                                                        "naked_identifier": "table2"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "whitespace": " ",
                                            "join_clause": [
                                                {
                                                    "keyword": "inner"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "whitespace": " "
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "keyword": "join"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "whitespace": " "
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "from_expression_element": {
                                                        "table_expression": {
                                                            "table_reference": {
                                                                "naked_identifier": "table1"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "whitespace": " "
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "join_on_condition": {
                                                        "keyword": "on",
                                                        "whitespace": " ",
                                                        "expression": [
                                                            {
                                                                "column_reference": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "naked_identifier": "table2"
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "dot": "."
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "naked_identifier": "colB"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "whitespace": " "
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "comparison_operator": {
                                                                    "raw_comparison_operator": "="
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "whitespace": " "
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "column_reference": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "naked_identifier": "table1"
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "dot": "."
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        "naked_identifier": "colA"
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "end_bracket": ")"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "whitespace": " "
                },
                {
                    "select_statement": {
                        "select_clause": {
                            "keyword": "select",
                            "whitespace": " ",
                            "select_clause_element": {
                                "wildcard_expression": {
                                    "wildcard_identifier": {
                                        "star": "*"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "whitespace": " ",
                        "from_clause": {
                            "keyword": "from",
                            "whitespace": " ",
                            "from_expression": {
                                "from_expression_element": {
                                    "table_expression": {
                                        "table_reference": {
                                            "naked_identifier": "cte2"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reconstrunct the query string given one of these dicts? I couldn't find anything on the [official API reference](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/api.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on sqlfluff's Slack and got an answer.
To achieve this you need more than just the simple API. You instance a Lexer and pass its results to a Parser object. Then, when calling `Parser().parse(lex_result)` you get a `FileSegment` which is composed by Segments that are also composed by Segments. You iter through them via `.segments` attribute.

Each Segment can return to string via the `.raw` attribute.

```py
from sqlfluff.core import Parser, Lexer


lexer = Lexer(dialect="postgres")
parser = Parser(dialect="postgres")

tokens, _ = lexer.lex(
    """with cte1 as (select colA from table1), cte2 as (select colB from table2) select * from cte1"""
)

obj = parser.parse(tokens)
print(obj.segments)
print(obj.segments[0].raw)
```

Output:

```bash
>> (<StatementSegment: ([L:  1, P:  1])>, <EndOfFile: ([L:  1, P: 93]) ''>)
>> with cte1 as (select colA from table1), cte2 as (select colB from table2) select * from cte1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think below code solves the problem, but I’m unfortunately not really sure it’s correct.

```py
def back_to_string(ast) -> str:
    actual_ast = ast['file']
    def bla(x):
        if isinstance(x, str):
            yield x
        elif isinstance(x, list):
            for l in x:
                yield from bla(l)
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
            for k,v in x.items():
                yield from bla(v)
    return "".join(bla(actual_ast))
```